# Keras on a GPU with less than 3.0 computing capability?

Tags: windows, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am working on a GPU server from my college with the computing capability less than 3.0, Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit operating system and 48GB RAM. I have tried to install tensorflow earlier but then I got to know that my GPU cannot support it. 
I now want to work on keras but as tensorflow is not there so will it work or not as I am also not able to import it?

I have to do video processing and have to work on big video datasets for Dynamic Sign Language Recognition. Can anyone suggest me what I can do to get going in the field of Deep Learning with such GPU server? Or if I want to work on CPU only, then will there be any problem in this field of video processing?

I also have an HP Probook 440 G4 Laptop with Windows 10 Pro so is it better than the GPU server I have or not?

I am totally new to this field and cannot find a way to work properly in it. 
Your opinions are needed right now!

The 'dxdiag' information for my laptop is shown [image: here] and [image: here_1].

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use tensorflow on the CPU, a GPU is not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Keras to work you need either Tensorflow or Theano. Your Laptop seems to have a GeForce 930M GPU. This card has a compute capability or 5.0 according to the NVIDIA documentation (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus). So you are better off with your Laptop if my research was right.

I guess you will use CNN with your video processing and therefore I would advise you to use a GPU. You can run your code also on a CPU but training will be much slower since GPUs are made for parallel computing and CPUs are not (the big matrix multiplication profit a lot from the parallel computing).

Maybe you could try a cloud computing provider if you think training is too slow on your laptop

Comment: I checked the specifications of my laptop on internet and it is showing that my laptop has discrete NVIDIA GeForce 930MX (2 GB DDR3 dedicated, switchable). I didn't know this, I thought it has only CPU. I am trying to download the required drivers for it and also how to switch to this GPU instead of the integrated Intel HD Graphics 620. But one thing I want to know is that the GPU server I have from my college has the NVIDIA TESLA C2050 GPU and cuda and tensorflow were not supported on it. Will I be able to work on keras and tensorflow on my laptop then?

Comment: quick and short, yes. your GPU has a compute capability of 5.0 (see anwser above). I would appreciate an up vote and accepted answer if this helped you

Comment: I tried to download the NVidia drivers for HP notebook by first detecting my laptop model through HP website which gives "HP ProBook 440 G4 Base Model Notebook PC" with "Windows 10 (64-bit) operating system". It is the link for the mentioned model: https://support.hp.com/in-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-probook-440-g4-notebook-pc/10477248/model/10477252?sku=W6N89AV     The link has tab "Open Downloads List" which has "NVIDIA Video Driver and Control Panel". But while installing it says - NVidia installer can't continue as the graphics driver couldn't find compatible graphics hardware.

Comment: Maybe the Nvidia tool is not working correctly on your system. Here is a link to the driver download itself. https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/134941 It Also might be, that your version of the laptop has no dedicated graphics card but an Intel HD Graphics 620  chip inside the CPU. Check your pc again if it really has a Nvidia card

Comment: Yes, I did that but again the same thing - the graphics driver couldn't find compatible graphics hardware. I checked my laptop and it has no NVIDIA control panel. It has DirectX12 integrated GPU but I couldn't find any other GPU through 'dxdiag' but when the HP website detected my laptop model, why it showed the discrete NVIDIA GeForce 930MX written there?

Comment: I don't know if its possible in comments, but can you post a screenshot of the display tap from your dxdiag call? If not, can you say what it says under device?

Comment: I have updated the question above with the snapshots of 'dxdiag' information for system and display.

Comment: Sadly I have to inform you, that you do NOT have the model with the NVIDIA graphics card, but one with the integrated into the Intel chip. You still can do deep learning on your laptop, but only with CPU support. This will slow down your training drastically on CNN and large datasets. If you are willing you could use cloud computing platforms like AWS or Azure. Or invest the money in a machine with a graphics card.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for clearing the doubt of GPU at least. Now instead of wasting my time to download the Nvidia drivers, I will do the alternative options as you said. :)